# Putting items from a dictionary into a string

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to use data from a list of dictionaries in a string. For example

```
dict = [{'name':'Matt', 'age':'21'},{'name':'Sally','age':'28'}]

print(f"His name is {??} and he is {??} years old")
```

I need to know what to replace the question marks with to make it work.

I have looked a lot of stack overflow and found some things, but nothing to get one specific item. I found

```
print([item["name"]for item in dict])
```

Comment: maybe go through a tutorial rather than randomly searching SO for a magical answer. SO is not a tutorial service for super basic questions.

Comment: Do not use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict) as name for variables.

Comment: Your `print()` statement is clearly intended for just one person.  Did you want to print just one person, or all the people?

Comment: just one person. i'm going to need to do that same print statement for several of the different people but only 2 at a time. @JohnGordon

Comment: @Julien I did go through several web searches and SO searches before making this question. I couldn't find anything addressing my specific need. I apologize, I don't want to bother. I'm just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict = [{'name':'Matt', 'age':'21'},{'name':'Sally','age':'28'}]
```

`dict` is a list of dictionaries.  (Terrible variable name choice, by the way.  `dict` is already the name of something built-in to Python, so by using that as a variable name, you've lost its original meaning.  Plus, you're using `dict` to hold a list of people, so the name itself is not very meaningful.  `people` would be a much better name.)

Lists are accessed by an integer index.  So in this case, `dict[0]` is Matt's entry, and `dict[1]` is Sally's entry.

Now that you know `dict[0]` is Matt's entry, you can use the standard dictionary key syntax.

Matt's name is `dict[0]['name']` and his age is `dict[0]['age']`.

Likewise Sally's name is `dict[1]['name']` and her age is `dict[1]['age']`.

(All of this is very basic Python syntax.  What part, exactly, did you have trouble with?)

Comment: Thank you. The variable name dict was only for this example, it isn't in my game. You answered my exact question. I just wasn't sure the exact syntax to pull a single item from a dictionary, I looked but maybe i couldn't find anything because it is so basic. I'm still a beginner(obviously), I'm trying really hard to learn and I'll get there. i really appreciate you taking time to help teach me this.

Comment: I found many solutions using the for loop but i only wanted to print the information for one person.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the dicts, and then use the `[]` operator to get the `name` and `age` keys.

```
people = [{'name':'Matt', 'age':'21'},{'name':'Sally','age':'28'}]

for p in people:
    print(f"Their name is {p['name']} and they are {p['age']} years old")
```

```
Their name is Matt and they are 21 years old
Their name is Sally and they are 28 years old
```

Answer (score 1):

- For print **all** persons in the `dict`:

```py
for person in dict:
  print(f"His name is {person['name']} and he is {person['age']} years old")
```

output:

```
His name is Matt and he is 21 years old
His name is Sally and he is 28 years old
```

- For print **one** person in the `dict`, using his index (index `1` in this example):

```py
print(f"His name is {dict[1]['name']} and he is {dict[1]['age']} years old")
```

output:

```
His name is Sally and he is 28 years old
```